# html website url opens without .html extension. why?

Tags: html, file-extension

i have a html5 website, my query is when i open any url without .html extension  it opens why?

i want suggests,  so that all my url should open with .html extension only.

example.

right now url   http://www.abc.com/about-us  opens webpage, i want either it should redirect to http://www.abc.com/about-us.html  or should show 404 error.

Comment: We have no idea about your site's routing system. Do you use any frameworks like CodeIgniter? Or any .htaccess files?

Answer (score 1):

This is all based on the server configuration.  Sites like abc.com use [URL rewriting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine) to give you the ability to enter a "pretty" url (like abc.com/about-us) and get directed to the relevant content.

The default configuration on most hosting environments should only allow browsing to a page by its full name (ie yoursite.com/about-us.html).

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess, but most likely, you have Apache's MultiView feature enabled (or a similar mechanism on another web server). This feature selects one of many files that matches the request URL (sans extension), and has an extension that maps to the MIME type requested by the client through the `Accept` header. So, for example, if your have both `foo.txt` and `foo.html` in your docroot, and the client requests `/foo`, an `Accept` header that says `text/plain` will yield `foo.txt`, while `text/html` will give you `foo.html`.

The intended use is so that Apache can serve different files to different browsers based on their capabilities: for example, you can have a PNG and a GIF version of the same image, and Apache serves whatever the browser says it can handle.

Under normal circumstances, you want to disable MultiViews, because (especially when you have server-side scripting going on, say, PHP) it can lead to undesired (and sometimes baffling) results.

This mechanism, BTW, has absolutely nothing to do with HTML (4, 5, XHTML or whatever) - you will see the same behavior for image files, videos, stylesheets, plain text, anything.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason is **url rewriting**. In **.htaccess** file you can write different rule and conditions through which extension of page will not appear on browser.

For ex:http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/03/url-rewriting-examples-htaccess.html

Answer (score 0):

This is a technique called [**URL rewriting**](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/02/introduction-to-url-rewriting/) that can turn unsightly URLs into nice ones — with a lot less agony and expense than picking a good domain name. **It enables you to fill out your URLs with friendly, readable keywords without affecting the underlying structure of your pages.**

Many Web companies spend hours and hours agonizing over the best domain names for their clients. They try to find a domain name that is relevant and appropriate, sounds professional yet is distinctive, is easy to spell and remember and read over the phone, looks good on business cards and is available as a dot-com.

Or else they spend thousands of dollars to purchase the one they really want, which just happened to be registered by a forward-thinking and hard-to-find squatter in 1998.

**They go through all that trouble with the domain name but neglect the rest of the URL, the element after the domain name. It, too, should be relevant, appropriate, professional, memorable, easy to spell and readable. And for the same reasons: to attract customers and improve in search ranking.**